# ROS communication between both machines slow in router with out internet connection

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I’m running

1. Ros Kinetic under Ubuntu 16.04. The IP address are: 192.168.1.101 (master)  on RPi4 - Robot
2. Ros noetic, ubuntu 20.04, slave on my labtop 192.168.1.102 ,

Both are connected to the same router. I run turtlebot3_slam on the slave-labtop to read lidar data from master-rpi4. All computation task do on labtop. With internet connect to router, The ROS communication between both machines works great , I could run turtlebot3 navigation and slam on   slave-labtop with lidar data from master-rpi4.

With no internet connection, the ping command  responses slow from both sides and I could not run navigation or slam because slow responde data from lidar. Has anyone encountered this problem?

- Edited:
  For example: rostopic echo /scan
  With internet: It took 1s to show /scan data.
  Without internet: It take 20 s to setup connect and get /scan info.

After lidar /scan data show, ping rate is similar.
I thought the problem here, **It took alot of time to set direct connecttion between publisher (Rpi4) and subscriber (labtop) when without internet.** .

Thanh you   **aarsh_t**   ,I have tried to diffirent wifi router, set rosmaster on Labtop, same problem happen.

I have tried google search  but could not find solution.
I tried use multimaster but It does not improve Ros communication on router without internet.
http://wiki.ros.org/multimaster_fkie/Tutorials/Setup%20a%20ROS%20master%20synchronization

Some topic i have found:
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines
https://answers.ros.org/question/379170/start-roscore-slower-without-internet-connection/
https://answers.ros.org/question/218739/connecting-to-a-ros-master-without-internet/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400879/ros-communication-between-both-machines-slow-in-router-with-out-internet-connection/) by [BaBui](https://answers.ros.org/users/37344/babui/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2022-05-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2022-05-20**:
On the [second question](https://answers.ros.org/question/218739/connecting-to-a-ros-master-without-internet/?answer=400943#post-id-400943) you posted, Redhwan posted an answer to address your question. I suggest trying that and commenting on that answer if something goes wrong.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-05-23**:
It's possible this has to do with DNS timeouts.

Make sure you can either resolve all hostnames to their IP addresses *without* relying on your router, or don't use hostnames at all (by setting `ROS_IP` and `ROS_MASTER_URI` to IPs, instead of hostnames).

I'd recommend to use Wireshark to check what's going on in case of the slowdowns you observe.

> I tried use multimaster but I does not improve Ros communication on router without internet

I'd also recommend to stay away from more complicated setups -- which `multimaster_fkie` definitely is -- until you've figured out the cause of your problem, as adding more complexity typically does not help solving a problem like this.

**Comment by [aarsh_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/73435/aarsh_t/) on 2022-05-23**:\

> With no internet connection, the ping command responses slow from both sides

I do not think this can be the case. Try using different router or try connecting both via LAN for testing. I think upto 30-40ms of lag should be okay on wifi.

Try to setup the current time and update the RPi on robot.

Have you given thought that it might be due to the different versions of the ROS? I had somewhat similar issue and it got solved when I used similar version of ROS on both rosmaster and rosnode on PC.

One more thing I can think of is, Use your PC as rosmaster instead RPi, ssh to the Rpi and run nodes over there.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-05-23**:
Just to set this straight, as I keep seeing the terminology used here on ROS Answers:

> [..] of ROS on both master and slave.

ROS is a *peer-to-peer* framework. By definition all nodes are equal.

There are no slaves, nor masters.

The ROS master only functions as DNS server. It is not directly involved in communication between nodes.

**Comment by [aarsh_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/73435/aarsh_t/) on 2022-05-23**:
Haha yes, I should stop using it.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-05-24**:\

> Thanh you aarsh_t and gvdhoorn ,I have tried to diffirent wifi router, set rosmaster on Labtop, same problem happen.

I did not suggest any of these things.

**Comment by [aarsh_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/73435/aarsh_t/) on 2022-05-27**:
What is the ping rate with and without the internet connection? try to ping RPi from laptop terminal using `ping IP_OF_RPi`

**Comment by [BaBui](https://answers.ros.org/users/37344/babui/) on 2022-05-27**:
Dear, **aarsh_t**  ,  For example: rostopic echo /scan
With internet: It took 1s to get info.
Without internet: It take 20 s to setup connect and get /scan info.
After lidar /scan data show, ping rate is similar .
I thought the problem here, **It took alot of time to set direct connecttion between publisher (Rpi4) and subscriber (labtop) when without internet.**

**Comment by [aarsh_t](https://answers.ros.org/users/73435/aarsh_t/) on 2022-05-27**:
Do not run any rosnode or roscore and try to ping the IP of RPi from Laptop. If the ping is same with or without the internet, then the issue is with the ros and if not, then issue is with the wifi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**[FINALLY FIXED IT]**

**Reason:**

I don't know that I need synchronize time between master (rpi4 ) and slave ( My labtop) . When the router connect to internet, It automatic synchronize time. When disconnect,  time between master and slave is different.
And you need export enviroment parameter for ROS Communication:

```
Slave
export ROS_IP=$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1;}')
export ROS_HOSTNAME=$ROS_IP
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.100:11311
Master
export ROS_IP=$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1;}')
export ROS_HOSTNAME=$ROS_IP
```

**How to solve:**
Synchronize time use Chrony NTP Service [ Local Server ] and Client.
Reference this youtube link:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jxHP0Vycdaw&ab_channel=ICyb3r

**Server** My labtop

```
sudo apt install chrony -y
sudo nano    /etc/chrony/chrony.conf
```

Add these like to the last line in chrony.conf.
Allow client Ip to synchronize time

```
# Step the system clock instead of slewing it if the adjustment is larger than
# one second, but only in the first three clock updates.
makestep 1 3
local stratum 10
#manual
allow 192.168.1.0/24
smoothtime 400 0.01
```

**Client :** (Rpi4 board)

```
sudo apt install chrony -y 
sudo nano    /etc/chrony/chrony.conf
```

Disable update time from internet and add    server Ip (My labtop) by adding #    before them and add server
192.168.1.101 iburst prefer  at last line:

```
#pool ntp.ubuntu.com        iburst maxsources 4
#pool 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst maxsources 1
#pool 1.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst maxsources 1
#pool 2.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org iburst maxsources 2
server 192.168.1.101 iburst prefer
```

Check your setup:

```
sudo nano systemctl restart chrony    
chronyc tracking   
Reference ID    : C0A80165 (192.168.1.101)
Stratum         : 11
If it show like this, it is ok .
```

---

Originally posted by [BaBui](https://answers.ros.org/users/37344/babui/) with karma: 11 on 2022-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just to confirm a couple of things:

1. You're running Ubuntu 16.04 with ROS Kinetic on your RPi4 (IP 192.168.1.101)
2. You're running Ubuntu 20.04 with ROS Noetic on your laptop (IP 192.168.1.102)

Also what *exactly* have you added to your `bashrc` to try and set this up. An exact copy of the lines for both of them.

---

Originally posted by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) with karma: 1124 on 2022-05-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BaBui](https://answers.ros.org/users/37344/babui/) on 2022-05-26**:
I ran export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://pibot.local:11311 on both rpi4 and labtop. It worked well if router connect to internet. Without internet, It became very slow, I took 60- 240 second to start roslaunch.
This is bashrc file in may labtop :
[bashrc file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18MXm3V5eoBi2ndY7OopWmKiuSLpzg9km/view?usp=sharing)

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2022-05-30**:
Ah, okay, so what gvdhoorn said is

> by setting `ROS_IP` and `ROS_MASTER_URI` to IPs, instead of hostnames

So don't set it to `export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://pibot.local:11311` but set it directly to `export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.101:11311`

**Comment by [BaBui](https://answers.ros.org/users/37344/babui/) on 2022-05-30**:
Ya, I tried set it derectly to IP , It improve speed a little but not too much.

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2022-05-30**:
Did you do it for everything? `export ROS_IP=192.168.1.102` `export ROS_HOSTNAME=192.168.1.102` `export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.101:11311` and did you do the same on the raspberry pi?

Also, what's "a little"?

**Comment by [Joe28965](https://answers.ros.org/users/50769/joe28965/) on 2022-05-30**:\

- currently you're not exporting any `ROS_MASTER_URI` in your bashrc, since you've commented out all of them.